# How to mix itemized and enumerate items in the same list?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

I have a situation where I need to generate lists which contain a mix of numbered items and non-numbered items. Only the numbered items increment the counter. So something like this:

[image]

I know how to suppress the bullet by using `\item[]`, but it looks like whether an item is numbered (and increments the counter) is a function of the list environment, not the item itself. How can I do this? Stock LaTeX, please, I don't want to install more packages if I can help it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No packages needed really (though `enumitem` is *the* package to tame lists).  Use `enumerate`, which will do the numbering for you, then use `\item[\textbullet]` to force a bullet, `\item[]` to have nothing, and `\item` to have it numbered normally. You may want to define a shortcut to `\item[\textbullet]` like `\newcommand\bitem{\item[\textbullet]}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item[\textbullet] bullet
  \item[\textbullet] bullet
  \item[] no bullet
  \item[] no bullet
  \item number
  \item number
  \item[] no bullet
  \item number
  \item[\textbullet] bullet
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Fantastic --- just what I wanted. It's so much easier doing this in LaTeX than in HTML!